# How to make tkinter dialog box appear first?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new to python.

I've coded as follows. 
When user clicks the "Click button to setup CPE." button, the dialog window will appear and display the customer list.

My problem is that when the user clicks the "Click button to setup CPE." button, the `Listing()` function is working first. At that time the main window is dead. After finishing the `Listing()`, the dialog appears.

What can I do to make the dialog box appear first and display the info after the dialog box appears.

```
import Tkinter

class myWindow:
    addr = ''
    def __init__(self):

        self.mw = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.mw.option_add("*font", ("Arial", 15, "normal"))
        self.mw.geometry("+250+200")
        self.mw.title("Example of Custom Dialog-Window")

        # CPE
        self.btn_cpe = Tkinter.Button(self.mw, text = "Click button to setup CPE.", command = self.btnCPE)
        self.btn_cpe.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)
        self.mw.mainloop()


    def btnCPE(self):

        self.dialogwindow = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.dialogwindow.title("Dialog Window")
        self.dialogwindow.geometry("+500+350")
        self.dialogwindow.maxsize(500, 350)
        self.dialogwindow.minsize(500, 350)

        self.lab1 = Tkinter.Label(self.dialogwindow, text = "Checking info")
        self.lab1.pack()

        self.lab_addr = Tkinter.Label(self.dialogwindow, text = "Address : ")
        self.lab_addr.pack()

        # Refresh
        self.btn_refresh = Tkinter.Button(self.dialogwindow, text = "Refresh", command = self.refresh)
        self.btn_refresh.pack()

        self.btn_cpe_exit = Tkinter.Button(self.dialogwindow, text = "Exit", command = self.dialogwindow.destroy )
        self.btn_cpe_exit.pack()

        # This is the important line: It tells the main-window to lock:
        self.dialogwindow.grab_set() 

        self.Listing()
        self.lab_addr['text'] = "address : " + self.addr;

    def Listing(self):
        # access the db and set the address into self.addr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Tkinter

class myWindow:
    addr = ''
    def __init__(self):
        # CPE
        self.btn_cpe = Tkinter.Button(mw, text = "Click button to setup CPE.", command = self.btnCPE)
        self.btn_cpe.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)

    def btnCPE(self):

        self.dialogwindow = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        self.dialogwindow.title("Dialog Window")
        self.dialogwindow.geometry("+500+350")
        self.dialogwindow.maxsize(500, 350)
        self.dialogwindow.minsize(500, 350)

        self.lab1 = Tkinter.Label(self.dialogwindow, text = "Checking info")
        self.lab1.pack()

        self.lab_addr = Tkinter.Label(self.dialogwindow, text = "Address : ")
        self.lab_addr.pack()

        # Refresh
        self.btn_refresh = Tkinter.Button(self.dialogwindow, text = "Refresh", command = self.refresh)
        self.btn_refresh.pack()

        self.btn_cpe_exit = Tkinter.Button(self.dialogwindow, text = "Exit", command = self.dialogwindow.destroy )
        self.btn_cpe_exit.pack()

        # This is the important line: It tells the main-window to lock:
        self.dialogwindow.grab_set() 

        self.Listing()
        self.lab_addr['text'] = "address : " + self.addr;

    def Listing(self):
        print "hola"
        # access the db and set the address into self.addr

mw = Tkinter.Tk()
app=myWindow()
mw.option_add("*font", ("Arial", 15, "normal"))
mw.geometry("+250+200")
mw.title("Example of Custom Dialog-Window")
mw.mainloop()
```

& also,try not to include the UI part in the constructor. Tell me if it helps

Comment: No buddy. Pls add time.sleep(5) at Listing() function and test it.

Comment: Bro,I've given you the gist of it..the way you want to run **Listing()** is yours to figure out.
you can either use sleep or can even use a button to call it.Here,dialog is gonna appear first,rest is for you to decide
you can even call **Listing()** after the window is destroyed